# Post CLOB XML to URL by PL/SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, api, http, plsql

I have to send by POST my CLOB, XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<record>
 <ROW>
  <ID>49732</ID>
  <FILE_ID>1565</FILE_ID>
  <LASTNAME>TINPU</LASTNAME>
  <FIRSTNAME>VOLODYA</FIRSTNAME>
  <CITIZENSHIP>RU</CITIZENSHIP>
 </ROW>
</record>
```

to url, but i cant's with this code.
This XML sended to our java-servlet and parse it to the table in database, but message is empty. And where is no errors and exceptions. How can i do this? My nerves are over..

```
procedure afl_to_akr (p_result in CLOB) is
  l_url varchar2(690);
  req   utl_http.req;
  resp  utl_http.resp;
  l_out  CLOB;
BEGIN
  l_url := 'http://10.120.48.3:8180/ab-int/integroServlet?xml=';

   req := utl_http.begin_request(url => l_url, method => 'POST', http_version => 'HTTP/1.1');                                 
   utl_http.set_header(r => req, name => 'Content-Type', value => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   utl_http.set_header(r => req, name => 'Content-Length', value => length(p_result));
   utl_http.write_text(r => req, data => p_result);

   resp := utl_http.get_response(req);   

   begin
      utl_http.read_line(resp, l_out);
      utl_http.end_response(resp);   
exception
 when utl_http.end_of_body then
  utl_http.end_response(resp);
   end;
END;
```

Comment: Try a much simpler example from the documentation to find the error.

Comment: Look at the response code and messages. The CLOB value may be too big and you might need to manually break it into multiple write_text calls.

Comment: Try with `text/xml`, maybe your server is not supporting `applcation/xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way without your help..It's a pity!

```
procedure afl_to_akr(l_result in CLOB) is
  req   utl_http.req;
  res   utl_http.resp;
  l_out VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_url varchar2(690) := l_url := 'http://10.120.48.3:8180/ab-int/integroServlet';
  l_body CLOB;
begin
   req := utl_http.begin_request(l_url, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');
   utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
   l_body := 'xml=' || l_result;      
   utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(l_body));
   utl_http.write_text(req, l_body);
   res := utl_http.get_response(req);
   begin
      utl_http.read_line(res, l_out);
      utl_http.end_response(res);
   exception
      when utl_http.end_of_body then
         utl_http.end_response(res);
   end;  
end;
```